# LIKE and CONCAT in QueryDsl

Tags: querydsl

How to write this query in `queryDsl`

```
SELECT a.id, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM ancestors_table t where t.ancestors LIKE CONCAT('%,',a.id,',%') )
  FROM ancestors_table a;
```

I struggle with the `LIKE CONCAT('%,',a.id,',%')` part.

**THE SOLUTION**

```
where(t.ancestors.like(
                Expressions.stringTemplate("'%,'")
               .concat(Expressions.stringTemplate("{0}" , a.id ))
               .concat(Expressions.stringTemplate("',%'")) 
))
```

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely sure, but something like this:

```
where(t.ancestors.like(Expressions.asString("%").concat(a.id).concat("%")))
```

If `a.id` is a number then you need to convert it into a string:

```
where(t.ancestors.like(Expressions.asString("%").concat(a.id.stringValue()).concat("%")))
```

Comment: Hi i got this `The method concat(Expression<String>) in the type StringExpression is not applicable for the arguments (NumberPath<Integer>)`

Comment: @Youssef: well `concat()` doesn't make sense for numbers. And `LIKE` doesn't make sense either for numbers. Not in QueryDSL and not in SQL. You probably need some cast for that. You are not by any chance storing a comma separated list of values in the `ancestor` column? That is a really bad database design.

Comment: yes i'm doing that :D but why it's a bad design .. how can i make a hierarchical query that returns all descendants of a given id or a query that would return all ancestors of a given id ?